# Should I install Ubuntu using Wubi onto the same partition as Windows 7 or into a different partition?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, installation, partitioning, wubi

I have  250 GB hard drive with four partitions of equal size (`C:`, `D:`, `E:`, `F:`).  Windows 7 is installed in `C:`. I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi.

Should I install Ubuntu into the same partition where Windows is installed, or install into a separate partition such as `D:`? This is being used for Android development.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the choice matters as far as ubuntu is concerned, the only concern is that if you install on C, there is the possibility that windows will run out of space to do its thing. Similarly if you run out of space on ubuntu, it would be hard to expand as well.

Thus for simple cases either choice is fine, but id recommend going for a different drive

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't matter with wubi - its got a really light footprint as far as the system goes. It'll generate a image file to store its files, and hooks it into window's own bootloader. Install it whereever

That said, if you're going to go with a seperate partition, you might as well do a *full* ubuntu install, which is likely to be more reliable, to one of the other partitions. Wubi is a bit of a hack meant for when repartitioning isn't an option. You can also easily access the linux drive from windows if its a filesystem with an IFS available like EXT3 or 4 with a full install. You will replace ntldr with grub, but thats quite easily replaced.